# Java JSON code throwing an exception

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON string:

```
   [{"user_id":"123","email":"person@email.com","lat":"40.748329","lng":"-73.996223",
                    "first_name":"Alex","last_name":"Genadinik"}]
```

and this Java Code:

```
            try
            {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);

                Log.d( "NAME: " , "test: " + obj.getString("first_name") );       

            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                Log.d( "JSON ERRORZ: " , "some crap happened " + e.getMessage() );  
            }
```

But it throws this error:

```
[{"last_name":"Genadinik","first_name":"Alex","lng":"-73.996223","user_id":"1","email":"alex.genadinik@gmail.com","lat":"40.748329"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Any idea how I can fix this and simply just extract the values in the JSON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This JSON string is an array, not object, not the square brackets at the beginning ([look here](http://www.json.org/)). Use `JSONArray` instead, and extract the `JSONObject`s from it.

Comment: But if I use the JSONArray object, whats the function in there that gets me the value? I don't see anything applicable in the API - thanks!

Comment: Would it be something like this:    JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);
          
           JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(1);
           
              Log.d( "NAME: " , "test: " + o.getString("first_name") );

Comment: Yes. but start from index 0 :)]

Answer (score 3):

The error says it all. You're passing an array an it expects an object.

To fix your error you should remove the square brackets (`[`, `]`) from  your JSON string.

An object looks like:

```
{
    key: 'value'
}
```

Where as an array looks like:

```
[
    { key: 'value' },
    1,
    'some string'
]
```

Comment: But if I use the JSONArray object, whats the function in there that gets me the value? I don't see anything applicable in the API - thanks!

Comment: You could use the `getJSONObject(..)` method :).